# Can't build fuerte in fedora; fails on rosdep

Tags: ros, build-from-source, fedora

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I am following the fedora installation tutorial for fuerte ([here](http://www.ros.org/wiki/fuerte/Installation/Fedora)) and I got to the part where I run `rosdep update`, and I get many lines like this:

`laser_assembler: No definition of [pcl] for OS [fedora]`

For the dependencies:

`opencv2
python-qt-bindings
pcl
ros`

Is this a configuration problem on my end, or is it a known issue with ROS on fedora? I'm using Fedora 16, 64-bit.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/38193/can%27t-build-fuerte-in-fedora;-fails-on-rosdep/) by [Skinkworks](https://answers.ros.org/users/620/skinkworks/) on ROS Answers with karma: 11 on 2012-07-08

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Fedora does not necessarily have all rosdep rules defined.  You may need to [contribute some rules.](http://ros.org/doc/api/rosdep2/html/contributing_rules.html)

---

Originally posted by [tfoote](https://answers.ros.org/users/3/tfoote/) with karma: 58457 on 2012-09-15

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

See [this](https://code.ros.org/trac/ros/ticket/3929) ticket to solve some of the dependency issues.

However fixing `rosdep` rules will not solve the problem with `pcl` on Fedora since current standalone release (1.5.1) is not compatible with ROS. You either have to compile `pcl` by yourself or convert a native Ubuntu DEB package to RPM with `alien`. Some details are [here](http://answers.ros.org/question/43129/pcl_ros-build-error-in-fuerte-on-fedora-17-x64/).

---

Originally posted by [Boris](https://answers.ros.org/users/2873/boris/) with karma: 3060 on 2012-09-15

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1